# Custom logging handler and formatter with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pyinstaller

I have a Python package which I distribute as a single executable using PyInstaller.

I use the `logging` module in combination with file based configuration. To implement centralised, cloud-based logging, I decided to use the modules [loggly-python-handler](https://github.com/psquickitjayant/loggly-python-handler) and [python-json-logger](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger) to send the log information to [loggly](https://www.loggly.com). The latter transforms the log message to JSON, the first sends the (JSON) log message to Loggly using an HTTP(S) call.

An excerpt from my logging configuration (the actual `TOKEN` value has been removed, of course):

```
[handler_loggly]
class=loggly.handlers.HTTPSHandler
formatter=json
args=('https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/TOKEN/tag/test','POST')
level=CRITICAL

[formatter_json]
format= %(name)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s %(created)f %(funcName)s %(levelno)s %(lineno)d %(msecs)d %(levelname)s %(message)s
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
```

This works fine when running it on a machine where Python (and the necessary libraries) are installed. However, the executable generated by PyInstaller seems to be missing the required logging modules (as they are not imported anywhere in the source code, just referenced in the logging config).

Error output while running the executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 98, in _resolve
AttributeError: module 'pythonjsonlogger' has no attribute 'jsonlogger'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 64, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 41, in main
  File "<string>", line 28, in init_logger
  File "c:\python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
  File "c:\python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 123, in _create_formatters
  File "c:\python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 100, in _resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger'
main returned -1
```

**Attempt 1**

I've tried using PyInstaller's [hidden import functionality](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#listing-hidden-imports) to reference both modules:

```
pyinstaller \
--log-level=DEBUG \
--onefile \
--hidden-import=loggly \
--hidden-import=pythonjsonlogger main.py
```

Log file output:

```
3463 DEBUG: Hidden import: loggly
3463 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'loggly'
3463 DEBUG: Hidden import: pythonjsonlogger
3478 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pythonjsonlogger'
```

**Attempt 2**

Tried to specify the imports in the PyInstaller's spec file (excerpt below):

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Dev\\pyWebiExport'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['loggly.handlers.*', 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.*'],
             hookspath=None,
             …
```

Log file output:

```
3510 DEBUG: Hidden import: loggly.handlers.*
3510 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'loggly.handlers.*'
5694 ERROR: Hidden import 'loggly.handlers.*' not found
5694 DEBUG: Hidden import: pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.*
5694 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.*'
5709 ERROR: Hidden import 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.*' not found
```

**Version info:**

- Python 3.5.1 (Windows, x86)
- PyInstaller 3.0
- python-json-logger (0.1.4)
- loggly-python-handler (1.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by writing a [runtime hook](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#id74) for PyInstaller, which basically consists of an additional Python script with the following contents:

```
import pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger
import loggly.handlers
```

I saved these statements in the file `loggly_hook.py` and ran PyInstaller with the following arguments:

```
pyinstaller \
--log-level=DEBUG \
--onefile \
--clean \
--runtime-hook=loggly_hook.py main.py
```

PyInstaller log output:

```
10374 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
10389 INFO: Including custom run-time hook 'loggly_hook.py'
```